# Determine the limit and give and $\epsilon-N$ proof of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3+(-4)^n}{n^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulty working out this particular limit. My intuition is that it diverges because of the oscillating $(-4)^n$ which clearly grows much faster than then $n^2$ in the denominator. So in the limit the partial sequence would be oscillating between very large positive numbers and very large negative numbers. With that said my strategy would be to show that the limit of the reciprocal converges to $0$ since I have a theorem that says that a sequence diverges to infinity if and only if the reciprocal converges to $0$, so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2}{3+(-4)^n}=0.
\end{align*}
is what I'm working with. So far I have yet to come up with any promising avenue to construct an $\epsilon-N$ proof. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Estimate $|3 + (-4)^n|$. For sufficiently large $n$, such absolute value is greater than $3^n$.

Comment: "a sequence diverges to infinity if and only if the reciprocal converges to $0$", that's not true

Comment: Why not true? By definition this is right.

Comment: $-n$ diverges to $-\infty$, yet $1/(-n)$ diverges to $0$, for example. Another example, $1/((-1)^nn)$ diverges to $0$, yet $(-1)^nn$ doesn't diverge to $\infty$, nor to $-\infty$

Comment: "$1/(-n)$ diverges to $0$"? I honestly do not understand what you meant.

Comment: Rumpelstiltskin is correct. I misspoke when asking the question. The theorem states that for a sequence of positive values then the relationship holds.

Comment: Okay. This is the terminology difference here. For me, $a_n$ diverges to infinity means $|a_n| \to +\infty$. If you talk about $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ separately, then you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about showing $\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{3+(-4)^{2m}}{(2m)^2}=\infty$?

Comment: I don't understand why changing the variable to m helps.

Comment: I think it may be constructive to consider a subsequence that does not oscillate between positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1):

$4^n>n(n-1)(n-2)$ then

- for enen $n$:
  $$\dfrac{3+4^n}{n^2}>\dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n}\to+\infty$$
- for odd $n$:
  $$\dfrac{3-4^n}{n^2}<\dfrac{n-(n-1)(n-2)}{n}\to-\infty$$